# Swift ???does not have a member named?

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func btnAddSteps(sender: AnyObject) {
     println("the button was clicked")
     stepMgr.addSteps(txtSteps.text, desc: txtDesc.text);
     self.view.endEditing(true)
     txtSteps.text = ""
     txtDesc.text = ""
     self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

An error appears after writing the code above

> UITabBarController? does not have a member named selectedIndex

I tried several different ways but I could manage to solve. If anyone knows how to make this run please tell me!

Comment: @kupendra your edit made this question worse, because you separated out the ? from the tab bar controller, when in reality that is one statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

You're accessing the view controller's `tabBarController` property, which returns an optional (since it may not exist).

> 'UITabBarController?' does not have a member named 'selectedIndex'

An optional of type UITabBarController doesn't have a selectedIndex property - its just a container that may or may not hold a tab bar controller.

You need to use optional chaining:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Note the ?

This will unwrap and set the property, if the tab bar controller exists.